# Is an RST packet guaranteed to arrive?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, winsock

When a connection is terminated ungracefully (i.e. an `RST` packet has been sent to the other end), is the `RST` packet guaranteed to arrive? I mean how can the sending device know that the `RST` packet has been received by the other end if no `ACK` packet is sent back!

Comment: Note that the device sending the `RST` no longer cares if it has been received or not by the other side because it has already closed and released all state information.  `RST` means "nothing here".  More packets to there will just mean more (stateless) `RST` packets in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RST packets are not ACKed, so there is no 'guarantee' in the sense you mean. However if you keep sending to an endpoint which has reset the connection, it will keep issuing RST packets.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make both sides of the communication agree whether the connection is supposed to be shut down or not in all cases. This is the [Two Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) which is unsolvable. The `RST` is more of a "courtesy" and performance optimization. It allows for early cleanup in almost all cases.

But if you pull the cable all packets go into a black hole and it is unclear whether it is just a momentary timeout or a permanent loss of connectivity.